# Dart function variable/field type declaration

Tags: function, dart, types

I want to have a function as a class field like below (for use as a callback), but would like to specify what argument types the function is aloud and what it returns, e.g. it accept a `String` called `mystring` and returns a `Future<int>`, so the type might look like (pseudocode): `Function(String mystring -> Future<int>)` or something. I haven't been able to find anything like this in the docs, is something similar possible in Dart? Also I am not sure what the terminology for something like this is which makes it harder to search for.

```dart
class Test {
  Function myfunc;
  Test(this.myfunc) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The syntax is to place the return type before `Function` and put the parameters in parentheses:

```dart
class Test {
  Future<int> Function(String) myfunc;
  Test(this.myfunc);
}
```

You could also use a typedef:

```dart
typedef FunctionType = Future<int> Function(String);


class Test {
  FunctionType myfunc;
  Test(this.myfunc);
}
```